# How to make Carrierwave add random string to the file path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this kind of hot fix:

```
= image_tag "#{current_candidate.profile.photo_url}?stamp=#{SecureRandom.hex}"
```

The reason for this is that I made a "crop" feature, and when users recrop their photo - old version gets displayed from browser cache.

Anyway.

This `photo_url` is called in many places, and rather than making a helper & call it everywhere I thought it would be nice to configure uploader to do that.

Is that possible?

Note: filename can't be random. For other reasons.
I would imagine it has something to do with overriding `photo_url` method.

Comment: I dunno if I would use `SecureRandom.hex` in this kind of situation since the image may not have changed, but this would cause a refresh. Why not use something like `stamp=#{current_candidate.profile.updated_at.to_i}` so that it will only refresh when the user profile changes, not every time.

Comment: I think that you'd be better off creating a helper method or looking at the source to see if there is a `url` method that you can manipulate.

Comment: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files ?

Comment: so far I like this approach: `stamp=#{current_candidate.profile.updated_at.to_i}` (moved into profile method called `photo_url`)